# Mongoose findOneAndUpdate not returning raw Mongo response

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to determine whether the document was found in my findOneAndUpdate operation. If it wasn't, I return a 404 not found error. I figured I'd use the "passRawValue" option Mongoose provides, and check for a raw value- if raw is undefined, I know the doc was not found.

However regardless whether the doc is found or not, my raw value is undefined. I've verified that the doc I'm trying to update is in the DB at the time of the query by running a simple "findOne" query just before the update. Where am I going wrong?

```
let updateItemById = (userId, itemId, params, cb) => {

//this finds and prints the document I'm testing with -- I know its in the DB

  // Item.findOne({ "_id" : itemId, ownerId: userId }, (err, doc) => {
  //   if (doc) {
  //     console.log("This is the doc: ", doc);
  //   }
  // });

  Item.findOneAndUpdate({ "_id" : itemId, ownerId: userId },
    {
      $set: {
        params
      }
    }, { runValidators: 1, passRawResult: true}, (err, doc, raw) => {

    if (err) {
      //winston.log
      return cb(ErrorTypes.serverError(), false);
    }
    else if (raw) {
      return cb(null, true);
    }
    else {
      return cb(ErrorTypes.notFound(), false);
    }

  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi I have a hunch that you are passing params that has a property that doesn't exist in the document in the database. In such case, nothing was modified, hence db doesn't return raw as the third parameter.

**Update:**

So I did some few tests of my own, and I see that if we pass option strict:false then your code should work as intended. So your options section will look like this

```
    { runValidators: 1, passRawResult: true, strict: false, new:true}
```

**Explanation:**

Mongoose has a [strict option](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strict) which by default is true. It makes sure that the values being updated is defined in the schema. So when we provide the option strict as false, as described in the [mongoose documentation] (http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndUpdate) we can achieve updating document with new field.

I also added new:true option which will return you the updated document.

**P.S.**

I would like to add though, since our **upsert** is false, which means it won't insert new document when a match is not found, it will return null for doc, and you can simple check on that. Why are you checking on raw? Is there any particular reason for this?

Comment: oh, so what would be the approach if that's the case? My Item objects have optional properties that could get set in an update, so this is a use case of mine.

Comment: so the optional  properties aren't defined in the schema?

Comment: Hey checked it out- thanks for the response! Basically I just wanna be able to tell whether or not the server had found an object that matches the query to update. If it hasn't, I'd like to return 404 not found to the client- hence why I'm checking raw to see if any document was found (and updated) in the first place

Comment: @DavidTamrazov did adding "strict:false" option work for you though?

Comment: Unfortunately not- the properties I'm setting are all defined in the schema, and I actually rely pretty heavily on the integrity of the model. For now I've resolved to simply find the doc --> manually update --> save

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been awhile but I had the same problem here so I decided to leave an answer that maybe can help other people.

I was able to check whether the **findOneAndUpdate()** method found a document or not by checking if the **doc** parameter was null on the callback function:

```
async Update(request: Request, response: Response) {
  const productId = request.params.id;

  const query = { _id: productId };
  const options = { new: true };

  try {
    await Product.findOneAndUpdate(query, request.body, options, (err, doc, res) => {
      if (doc === null)
        return response.status(404).send({
          error: 'Product not found'
        })
      return response.status(204).send();
    });
  }
  catch (err) {
    return response.status(400).send({
      error: 'Product update failed'
    });
  }
}
```